# Pass pointer by value

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

Having a following function:

```
virtual HRESULT GetMediaType(
  int iPosition,
  CMediaType *pMediaType
);
```

How do I call it so that pMediaType is passed by reference and everything done to the object in the method is preserved?

Comment: Exactly how you'd pass any other type by reference...

Comment: Unless you need to change what `pMediaType` points to, this is not a problem. Any changes to the object's contents apply directly to the object who's address you pass.

Answer (score 5):

Because you give the object to the function as a pointer, everything done to the object in the method is preserved.

You can call it by the following way:

```
CMediaType pMediaType;
GetMediaType( 0, &pMediaType );
```

Comment: but if i declare it as a pointer like: CMediaType *pMediaType, the correct syntax would be GetMediaType(0, pMediaType); Right?

Answer (score 0):

As you currently have it:

> ```
> virtual HRESULT GetMediaType(
>   int iPosition,
>   CMediaType *pMediaType
> );
> ```

in code like this:

```
CMediaType mediaType;
...GetMediaType(position, &mediaType);
```

anything you do on `pMediaType` inside `GetMediaType()` body is *"preserved"* at the call site, since you are passing a *pointer* to `mediaType`.

However, if you want to create a new instance of `CMediaType` inside `GetMediaType()` body, and return it as an output pointer value that the caller must somehow free after use (kind of like COM `IUnknown::QueryInterface()`), then you can use **double-indirection pointers**, e.g.

```
virtual HRESULT GetMediaType(
  int iPosition,
  CMediaType** ppMediaType    // [OUT] Created by the method, must be freed by the caller
);
```

Usage sample:

```
CMediaType* pMediaType = nullptr;
...GetMediaType(iPosition, &pMediaType);

... use pMediaType ...
...
... somehow release pMediaType
```

Anyway, try to apply the KISS rule, keeping the code as simple as possible (so avoid double-indirection pointers, if you can).